# Python: open one or two files depending on second default parameter when not None using argparse

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, default, argparse

Beeing new to Python I am trying to figure out the best way to pass parameters using argparse to functions when these can be either None (default) or is given a value. 
In the below the function `func` - called from function `main` - can either run with one argument `f1` or two `f1` and `f2`.
Should one do a test in function `func` to check for the value of `f2` ? Or are there smarter ways ?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def func(f1, f2 = None):
   if f2 is None:
     with open(f1, "r") as f1:
       #Something...
   if f2 is not None:    
     with open(f1, "r") as f1, open(f2, "r") as f2:
       #Something else...

def main():
  parser = ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--f1', dest='f1', required=True)
  parser.add_argument('--f2', dest='f2', required=False, default=None)
  o = parser.parse_args()
  #Call functions:
  func(o.f1, o.f2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Would something along this construct be possible:

```
def func(f1, f2 = None):    
  with open(f1, "r") as f1:
    if f2 is not None:
      with open(f2, "r") as f2:
       #Something and something else...
```

Comment: `if f2 is (not) None` is a good test.  `None` is the most reliable indicator of a default value.  And opening the files in a `with` context is good PY3 practice.

Comment: It just appear annoying and waste of code if the code in "Something..." and "Something else..." are similar. So you have two similar blocks to handle the  case with a second parameter ?

Comment: To be picky I'd probably use the `if ... else` pairing.  Not that it make much difference in program efficiency, especially with such a simple test.

Comment: Sure. But with the above scheme you risk have two large almost redundant code blocks in either case. It would be nice if one could always use something like `with open(f1, "r") as f1, open(f2, "r") as f2:` even though f2 is `None`

Comment: I was going to suggest nesting the `if f2 is not None` context in the `f1` context, but I don't see how that gets around separate blocks.  Another possibility is to define a dummy `f2` context.  In http://bugs.python.org/issue13824 I had to define a dummy wrapper to `stdin` files to prevent them from being closed.

Comment: Yeah, Ill take a look at that thanks, and maybe make a post in Code Review.

Comment: By the way: would this be possible `with open(f1, "r") as f1: if f2 is not None: with open(f2, "r") as f2: ...` (with proper indentation!). Was this what you meant above ?